# How to use Timeshift to backup EXT4 filesystem on a separate BTRFS partition?

Tags: linux-mint, backup

I have seen several articles on similar topics, but none directly address my question/problem.
First, I want to use Timeshift GUI rather than CLI.
I have a single physical drive and want to install Linux Mint on an EXT4 partition and create a 20g BTRFS partition for backup images on the EXT4 system partition.

Is it possible?
Admittedly, I don't know much about any of this. But I do know I previously installed the OS on EXT4 and formatted a USB stick with BTRFS and there appeared to be no option to backup to that.

Answer (score 0):

Instructions on how to use Timeshift are quite easy to find, and most of them actually refer to GUI. For example, here's a detailed one describing how use USB drive for backups on [Linux Mint](https://linuxhint.com/timeshift_linux_mint_usb/). Even the project's [Github page](https://github.com/teejee2008/timeshift) shows the GUI. The Github page also says:

> Timeshift is designed to protect system files and settings. It is NOT a backup tool and is not meant to protect user data. Entire contents of users' home directories are excluded by default.

... and continues to show exactly how to include them :-D

I've seen nothing that limits the choice of FS types except that MS file systems aren't supported. The only FS-specific thing is that if your system is installed on a brtfs FS, you can do snapshots using brtfs in-built snapshot mechanism. For other FS:s the available option is rsync.

Why you couldn't backup on your USB stick is outside the scope here. With no info there's absolutely no way to determine what happened - guesswork helps no-one. If you run into problems you can't figure out you can always post a new question.

---

*To get better help in the future, please include things like the exact versions of your Linux distro and whatever tool or utility you're having problems with; description of what exactly you are trying to do and how; what exactly do you expect to happen; what exactly does happen and at what point. Include any error- or other messages you get. For clarity it's best to paste them in*

```
as code using
the squiggly brackets {}
```

*on the toolbar. Sometimes screenshots can be helpful, but* don't *use them for error messages etc. Nobody wants to write them in from a screenshot when they could be simply copy-pasted from your question.*

Comment: Yes, sorry, I was not clear at all it turns out!  My system FS is EXT4.  And I think that is where the problem lies.  I don't really want to run my system on BTRFS, as I've read about instability issues compared to EXT4.  I was thinking it could only do snaps if the STORAGE was BTRFS, but that the system didn't matter.  I really want those snaps, so maybe I have to just bite the bullet.  LOL
Thank you for your response!  I tried to mark your answer as the solution but even though it's my question, I don't have enough rep to vote.  LOL  So annoying.

Comment: I don't think there's a problem, AFAIK you can do snapshots, you just need to use rsync since btrfs method isn't available :-) Voting is by the arrows icons and requires rep, only the OP can accept the answer, no rep needed. Click the swoosh-sign under the down-arrow :-)